How to derive the 1/s rule for Laplace transform of an integral?
How do we derive the rule $\mathcal{L}\{ \int_0^t f(\tau) d\tau\}=F(s)/s$ where $F(s)=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$ and the symbol $\mathcal{L}$ represents the Laplace transform operator ?

Let's denote $g(t):=\int_0^t f(\tau)\text{d}\tau$. We know from the fundamental theorem of calculus that $g$ is differentiable and that $g'(t)=f(t)$. Moreover $g(0)=0$. Therefore, integrating by parts,
$$\mathcal{L}\{g(t)\}(s)=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-st}g(t)\text{d}t=-\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-st}}{-s}f(t)\text{d}t=\frac{1}{s}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-st}f(t)\text{d}t=\frac{F(s)}{s}$$

Why is it always so simple when others do it :)
